# hlsl - isinf() is not working as expected

Tags: directx, hlsl

I'm trying to use the below code snippet to get rid of `NaN`s and `inf`s in my `float3` variable.

```
float3 tmp = ...;
bool colorsNan = any(isnan(tmp));
bool colorsInf = any(isinf(tmp));
tmp = (colorsInf || colorsNan) ? float3(0, 0, 0) : tmp;
```

However, while `isnan()` seems to be working, there are still `inf`s after the operation. What is wrong?

Comment: What format are you writing the results of the shader to determine that there are INfs?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn float32 I think.